# 1 video view = 1 Parse request? How to improve that?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, parse-platform

I'm working on an app a little like Vine, where several looped videos are displayed on the screen of the user. I need to count one view per loop. It means, if the user repeat the video 5 times, it will count 5 views. And this is the model I want to use for every videos of my app.

I use Parse for my back-end and a webview to show the videos. It means that I use Javascript to send requests to Parse, with Ajax calls.

My problem is that I don't really know how to limit the number of requests sent to Parse when I add a view on a video.

Maybe I should save the video views to a MySQL database and then, once a day with a cron task, save the MySQL results to Parse? I don't really know how to proceed, but I really need to limit the number of requests to Parse.

How would you design this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to limit the number of requests?

Comment: @danh Because I want to optimize my app. So I don't pay too much for a big number of requests on Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to not optimize too early.  There should be plenty of time, as you accrue zillions of users, to improve the design.

If you want to improve it early (and still use parse), keep the object that tracks views "pinned" locally ([see this blog entry](http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/)).  Update the view count as often as needed, then update parse on an [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/).

The app may become inactive at any time, and if unsaved views have been counted since last time the timer fired, then there's one more problem to solve.  The app delegate gets told that `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and can request a moment to finish "one last thing".  [See here under "Executing Finite Length Tasks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

There (iIn the dispatch block suggested by the sample code), save the object that counts views (`saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`), invalidate the timer, and tell iOS you're done with `[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];`

Answer (score 1):

What I should is store the video's somewhere else and save 1 view per click.

You can save this click in the background using something like this:

```
userClick.saveInBackground()
```

It saves the click in a background proces so the user doesn't have to wait for the sync with Parse.

note: You should use Bolts (https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) to get saveInBackground() working.

*** edit ***

Maybe it's smart to sync with parse every x amount of clicks, maybe 5 or 10. To limit the amount of requests.